# MySQL: Calculating time between two dates

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a function that when I pass a datetime parameter through it, it then determines the time difference. I also want to return 0 if the orig_date is in the future, or return the hours difference if it is in the past. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong? The error I get is `Incorrect DATETIME value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` I haven't done an if statement yet to check if it's in the future or not, any guidance on this would be appreciated as I have no idea how it would be done.

Here is my function so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION table.calc_time(orig_date datetime)
RETURNS int
 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    #DECLARE elapsed_time datetime;
    DECLARE today datetime;
DECLARE difference int;
SET today = now();
SET difference = timediff(orig_date, today)/3600;
    RETURN (difference);
END
```

Comment: It works for me. How are you calling it?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8XGozenv3knw4p23DV1poF/0

Comment: @Barmar Interesting.. I'm calling it from a select statement that creates a view. I wonder if the issue is when the datetime that is being passed in is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ?

Comment: I get an error for that, but the error says the incorrect date is `0000-00-00 00:00`. Where is `62136` coming from in your use?

Comment: @Barmar I have just updated it now. I had a typo in the sql I have and now the error is for 0000-00-00 00:00:00 so I'm not sure how to allow these through.

Comment: There's a SQL_MODE related to allowing zero datetime.

Comment: But why do you need to use that time? Maybe you should declare this to take a VARCHAR. Test if it's `0000-00-00` first.

Comment: I'm using a db I can't touch so some of the datetimes are 0000-00-00 00:00:00. The data type is definitely a datetime type.

Comment: If you declare the parameter as VARCHAR, the datetime will be converted to a string, and you won't get the error.